# Simple HTML form with Select Option disabled, is allowed to submit in Chrome and IE. Works fine in Firefox

Tags: php, html, forms, html-select

I have a simple HTML form that submits to another page. Select options are being used with one being 'disabled' and 'selected'. In Chrome and Internet Explorer this form is allowed to be submitted, but in Firefox it works correctly and tells me to select an option.

Code:

```
<form name=cars method=post action=submit.php>
    <select required>
        <option value="volvo" disabled="disabled" selected>Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="vw">VW</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <input type=submit value=submit name=submit>
    </select> 
</form>
```

In FireFox, as expected, when I hit the submit button, I get the message:

"Please Select an item in the list."

On IE and Chrome it tries to submit to the submit page.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the HTML spec section that says which behavior is correct?

Comment: Hm...it could be to do with the browser interpretation of "disabled" vs "selected". I'm guessing that IE and Chrome consider Volvo to be selected (via the HTML markup), even though it's disabled. Is that 'selected' part of some requirement?

Comment: Why do you have your `<input type=submit>` inside the `<select>` ???? That isn't valid. The only elements allowed inside a `<select>` are `<option>` and `<optgroup>`.

Comment: @Katana314 Selected would eventually be changed to something like "Select an option".  Which is why i want it to be disabled so you can't submit the option that says "select an option"

Comment: @Spudley I originally didn't have it that way, I was just moved it up there for testing, it still works the way I want it in firefox with it there.  I've tried it inside and outside of the </select> and it behaves the same way.

Comment: @Barmar This is what I found from W3:          The disabled attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that an option should be disabled.

A disabled option is unusable and un-clickable.

The disabled attribute can be set to keep a user from selecting the option until some other condition has been met (like selecting a checkbox, etc.). Then, a JavaScript is required to remove the disabled value, and make the option selectable.

Comment: @user3258200 Where does that say anything about whether the `required` criterion is met when a disabled option is selected? That option prevents the _user_ from selecting the option, but it can still be selected from HTML or Javascript

Comment: Barmar appears correct based on the docs - it doesn't base 'required' status on the disabled attribute, but on whether the option's `value` is not an empty string. Try adding this first: `<option value="" selected>-Select a value-</option>` (you mentioned you were going to add that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above solution will work in all browsers except IE 7-8-9, As required attribute;

```
IE 10: works fine.
IE 9: the required attribute doesn't trigger validation of a field.
IE 7 & 8: the required attribute appears to prevent validation of a field.
```

Ref 'required' attibute support in different browsers:

```
http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-select-required.html
```

Alternative solution can be JQuery.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the `select` already has a value selected. You have to put a `option` without a value, something like this. Also, I'll help you and clean your code:

```
<form name="cars" method="post" action="submit.php">
    <select name="car" required>
        <option value="">Select a car...</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="vw">VW</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and it works correctly in firefox, still.  However, Chrome will not even dsiplay the "select a car..." option and IE will allow me to submit the form without having to change the option.

Comment: I cleared the cache on chrome and it is working properly now.  No luck with IE yet.  Thanks for your help getting it to work on Chrome, however!

Comment: can you please specify browser versions? its html5 validation and it will not work in older browsers, specially in IE8

Comment: @AamirShahzad I am using IE9.